# Efficient way to pass JSON from PHP 

Tags: php, sql, json

Here is a JSONArray I have:

```
 [{"items_id":"13","total":"1"}, {"items_id":"216","total":"0"},{"items_id":"16","total":"1"}]
```

Sometimes, each object has more than two properties (attributes?).  But I am just showing the principle here.  In Java, I only need to grab "total".  I don't need "items_id".

I assume it shows up because here is my MySQL query in PHP:

```
$count_query_result=mysql_query("
SELECT items.items_id, 
COUNT(ratings.item_id) AS total
FROM `items`
LEFT JOIN ratings ON (ratings.item_id = items.items_id)
WHERE items.cat_id = '{$cat_id}'  AND items.spam < 5
GROUP BY items_id ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM items.item) ASC;");
```

Here is my JSON output (I have only displayed one of three queries above):

```
print(json_encode(array($output,$output2,$output3)));
```

I only want three properties encoded in JSON (one in each of the three output variables).  I want the properties "total", "rate" ,and "item".

So my question is, can I get rid of the unneeded items_id property?  Or do I even NEED to?  (I know I need it in the SQL to make the query work -- but how can I remove it in the JSONArray?)

I am thinking if I have a list with hundreds or thousands of items, I can save half the space (and time?) by only outputing the JSON property I need  -- is this thinking correct?

**Edit**:  More code as requested:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($count_query_result))
    $output[]=$row;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($average_query_result))
    $output2[]=$row;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($items_query_result))
    $output3[]=$row;

print(json_encode(array($output,$output2,$output3)));
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSONObject to parse the String. Just put the string as an parameter in the constructor of the JSONObject.

```
jObject = new JSONObject(myString);
```

After you can retrieve all variables out of the JSONObject.

For the php side:

Use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) end json_encode to switch betweeen json and mixed variable.
Once you have you mixed variable, delete the stuff you don't need and convert it back to json.

Comment: I know that is how I get the single object I need in Java/Android - but I am asking about the "handoff" method in PHP.  IS there a way to addres this before it even gets to the Java?

Comment: Ok, fair question.  At the time, I thought it made sense.  But after I asked it, it became clear that this was much more php oriented.  I suppose I can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/unset

Unset the unneeded values, then output json

Comment: Well this almost works unless I am doing wrong.  I am doing this unset($row['items_id') when I loop through results.  I did it only for first $output and it worked fine.  Second $output2 said '[false]'.  So it somehow adversely affects the other outputs?

Comment: Hm, can you post more of your code how you get from SQL to $output, $output2 etc?

Comment: Ok, I have done that.  I also am figuring out more of what I am trying to do and added that explanation as well...

Comment: Not sure that will work since items_id is required for the query to work.

Comment: It will, as you're telling mysql: `Grab for me the ID and Count(ratings.itemid)`. Just try it and report back if it didn't work :)

Comment: well it appears to work, but the JSON output is now {"0":"1","total":"1"}.  The question was how to completely drop that first half of the object. So it would be {"total":"1"}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need it in your SQL query. If you need data from a database just in the context of the query, you don't need to `SELECT` it. Try doing just the:

> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`